# Weird characters showing in my blog post URL

Tags: java, php, css, url

I have a Wordpress site in Hindi, when I am sharing any post to Facebook or twitter the shared URL shows weird characters,how to make the URL simple as it should be.

It shows like this.
https://gethow.in/%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9A-%E0%A4%87%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%9C%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88-%E0%A4%94%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%87-%E0%A4%95i/

Comment: When I use https://www.urldecoder.org/ to url-decode that, it decodes it into `https://gethow.in/सर्च-इंजन-क्या-है-और-कैसे-कi/`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your original URL contains non-alphanumeric characters. The URL will then be automatically encoded to avoid misunderstood caused by special characters that might have a special meaning (such as '#' or '/') that could alter your URL. It's like a rule of thumb in almost every URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u sir i changed the special characters in the permalink and now it's working fine.
www.Gethow.in